# CakePhp CSS problem!

Tags: php, cakephp

Problem is about CakePhp. If I give permission to required directories CSS does not work. Sample URL:  [link text](http://www.yemeklog.com/cphp/)

Isn't this weird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in IE: It's a Firefox specific problem.

Your CSS file is not outputting the `Content-type: text/css` header, which makes Firefox ignore it as a style sheet. You will notice a warning to that effect in Firefox's error console.

I don't know Cake, but I'm sure there is a native way to remedy this.

A quick fix would be adding

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: text/css");

?>
```

to the top of `cake.generic.css` (if that is a PHP file).

If it's a real CSS file and not a rewritten URL (as I said, I don't know Cake), your web server doesn't seem to be taking care of sending the right content type - maybe something for the admin to fix.

If the admin can't fix it, you could try adding a `.htaccess` file to your project (or editing the existing one) containing

```
AddType text/css .css
```

Comment: Oh thanks Pekka. I added below code to my .htaccess file.

<FilesMatch "\.(css)$">
 SetHandler text/css
</FilesMatch>